# ssh passwordless login fails with permission denied (publickey)

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to set up passwordless ssh on two fresh linux VM's from VM A to VM B but I'm having permissions issues. I installed openssh-server on both vm's and configured /etc/ssh/sshd_config as follows:

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
```

All other fields are their default values. On VM A I ran `ssh-keygen -t rsa` with the default options. I tried to use `ssh-copy-id` but I got a permission denied(publickey) error. I then manually copied id_rsa.pub into authorized_keys on VM B. I used `chmod 700` for ~/.ssh, `chmod 600` for ~/.ssh/id_rsa, and `chmod 644` for ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, and ~/.ssh/known_hosts on both VM's. After running ssh -v VM-B I get the following output:

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to hadoop-slave-1 [192.168.86.134] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hduser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hduser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hduser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hduser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 45:48:fd:f0:db:1a:2a:c0:80:17:ec:18:5a:dd:f2:a5
debug1: Host 'hadoop-slave-1' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/hduser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hduser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hduser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: When debugging sshd access issues, I often find that it helps to run sshd on the remote machine in non-daemon mode, e.g. `sshd -D -d -p 8022`. Then `ssh -p 8022 remotehost` from the other machine. sshd tends to produce more informative error output than ssh does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to follow [Password-less logins with OpenSSH](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152)

in particular this should work:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub username@mystery
```

> This will prompt you for the login password for the host, then copy the keyfile for you, creating the correct directory and fixing the permissions as necessary

Comment: I had tried this before and had a permissiondenied(publickey) error but this worked when I re-enabled password authentication temporarily. I also had to use `ssh-add` before using `ssh-copy-id` which I had neglected to do before.

Comment: FYI, I created a small script at https://github.com/centic9/generate-and-send-ssh-key which runs the necessary steps in one go and additionally ensures all the file/directory permissions which always caused me headaches...

Comment: I am facing same issue could you please help in this.

Answer (score 5):

Another cause of permission issues is the permissions set on the home directory. Check if this is 755 or less.

See http://www.openssh.org/faq.html#3.14 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This line in the log you posted doesn't look right:

```
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Could you try:

```
ssh-copy-id remotemachine_username@remotemachine
```

Comment: Just so you know: on IBM AIX this doesn't work because there is no `ssh-copy-id`. `chmod -R 755 ~/.ssh` works fine though.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the PasswordAuthentication no to yes

Comment: This could easily by a comment.

Answer (score 0):

After completing these steps, hduser will be able to login using ssh keys without having to use password authentication on VM B. (note: we'll enable password authentication while working, but disable it again once everything is in order)

1. As root, open a terminal on VM B
2. Configure sshd_config to temporarily allow password authentication and ensure that your  root user can log back in if connection is lost during any part of this process.

   `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

   - Set PermitRootLogin to "yes" (we won’t be leaving it this way)
   - Set PasswordAuthentication to "yes" (this is also temporary)
   - Save changes and return to terminal

   `ctrl + o` then `Return/Enter`

   `ctrl + x`
3. Restart sshd services

   `sudo systemctl restart sshd`
4. Become hduser

   `su - hduser`
5. Remove /home/hduser/.ssh and replace it with a new (empty) ~/.ssh folder. Doing this as hduser ensures that hduser can write keys to this folder without having to specify ownership/group permissions with chmod (a common failure point in this process).

   `rm -r ~/.ssh`

   `mkdir ~/.ssh`
6. Let's call the current terminal "VM B Terminal." Keep VM B Terminal open and spawn a new terminal on VM A; we'll call this "VM A Terminal."
7. In VM A Terminal, we'll check for an "id_rsa.pub" file

   `ls ~/.ssh`
8. If you see an "id_rsa.pub" file in here and know it to be a good key, you can safely move to the next step. Otherwise, generate a new key.

   `ssh-keygen`

   - Use the default options by pressing Enter/Return and typing "yes" when asked about saving the new key. You should now have a file called “id_rsa.pub” in your ~/.ssh folder.
9. Use ssh-copy-id to copy hduser's credentials to the server. If ssh-copy-id is unavailable, scp is a good alternative.

   Option 1: `ssh-copy-id hduser@<ip-address>`

   Option 2: `scp -r ~/.ssh hduser@<ip-address>:/home/hduser/.ssh`

   - If successful, move on to the next step; otherwise, share your terminal output for further troubleshooting.
10. Switching back to VM B Terminal

    `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

    `PasswordAuthentication no`

    - Save changes and return to terminal
11. Restart sshd services

    `sudo systemctl restart sshd`
12. From VM A Terminal, connect over ssh as hduser. Note: if hduser’s ssh-key is password protected (this is recommended), enter the file password when prompted.

    - Congratulations on your success! You may now secure your server.
13. Configure sshd_config with production settings

    `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

    `PermitRootLogin no`

    - Save and exit

    `systemctl restart sshd`
14. Test hduser's connection again before closing out VM B terminal.